# How to return multiple rows using LINQ lambda expression from SQL Server 2014?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I'm trying to fetch data from SQL Server 2014 using LINQ lambda expression which is the requirement of my project. But as I'm new to LINQ, I think I'm doing something wrong with the code here and I'm getting an error.

I can fetch only one row without any error but if I put condition to fetch multiple row then I get error.

Here is my code - this is the repository class:

```
    public DettagliModel GetByIdDoc(int id)
    {
        using (var dbCtx = new USDevEntities())
        {
            var dettagli = dbCtx.Dettaglis.Where(x => x.IDDoc == id);

            if (dettagli != null)
            {
                return ConvertTo(dettagli); // Getting error here 
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public DettagliModel ConvertTo(Dettagli entity)
    {
        var model = Mapper.Map<DettagliModel>(entity);
        return model;
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'DAL.Service.Entity.Dettagli'    Core.Service

This error is hitting while writing the code but if I put after

```
   .Where(x => x.IDDoc == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

then the error goes off.

Please suggest me what can I do to solve this as I need to fetch multiple rows so I cannot use `FirstOrDefault()` method. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using automapper?

Comment: yes I'm using it.

Comment: I have included that tag in your question because it's relevant

Comment: Thanks @octavioccl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` extension method returns an `IQueryable<T>`, which means it is more than one element. If you want to map multiples entities to a different model using Automapper, then I suggest you use [`ProjectTo<T>`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) extension method:

```
public IEnumerable<DettagliModel> ConvertTo(IQueryable<Dettagli> entities)
{

    return entities.ProjectTo<DettagliModel>().ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<DettagliModel> GetByIdDocs(int id)
{
    using (var dbCtx = new USDevEntities())
    {
        return ConvertTo(dbCtx.Dettaglis.Where(x => x.IDDoc == id));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your code but the ProjectTo<DettagliModel>() line is showing error that "Does not contain a definition of ProjectTo". COuld you please tell me how I implement this?

Comment: you need to add the namespace. I don't remember the name. Wait a second

Comment: `using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;`

Answer (score 0):

First, this will never be null:

```
var dettagli = dbCtx.Dettaglis.Where(x => x.IDDoc == id);
```

Also, don't return `null` when something is `IEnumerable<T>`, use `Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.

---

Now, your method looks to return a single `DettagliModel`, which `ConvertTo` creates from a single `Dettagli`.

You might need to change the return type to `IEnumerable<DettagliModel>`

With that out the way you can now just use `.Select` to project the database entities into your own types:

```
return
    dettagli.Select(d => ConvertTo(d)); 
    //or just dettagli.Select(ConvertTo); if you like.
```

This will be a lazy collection, so I would probably convert this to a non lazy one using `.ToList()` on the end (and followed by `.AsReadOnly()` or use `.ToArray()` YMMV).

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(x => x.IDDoc == id).ToList();
```

returns `List<dbCtx.Dettaglis>`